# How to find maximum value of an image in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

I want to find the maximum value of the image but I got an error

```py
    import cv2
    image = cv2.imread('photo.jpg')
    mask = image[:,:,2]
    (min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(image) 
    print(max_val)
```

**ERROR**

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\minmax.cpp:1504: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (cn == 1 && (_mask.empty() || _mask.type() == CV_8U)) || (cn > 1 && _mask.empty() && !minIdx && !maxIdx) in function 'cv::minMaxIdx'
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195721/how-does-cvmask-should-look-like-for-opencv-minmaxloc

Comment: try it without the mask parameter first, just to rule out the potential issues. Also there is a possibility that its an error due to version. current opencv is at 4.7.x.x while yours is at 4.6.x.x

Comment: This is an RGB image, right?  How do you define "maximum value"?

Answer (score 1):

min max locs are defined across each channel

```py
for i in range(3):
  (min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(image[:,:,i])
  print(max_val)
```

Doc clearly says

**The function do not work with multi-channel arrays**. If you need to find minimum or maximum elements across all the channels, use Mat::reshape first to reinterpret the array as single-channel. Or you may extract the particular channel using either extractImageCOI , or mixChannels , or split .

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab473bf2eb6d14ff97e89b355dac20707